# using value from select as parameter in spring form to get object by id

Tags: jquery, forms, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

When I select an option from a select box, in a form, I want to get the input fields of the form to get populated with the values from the object selected above every time the selection changes. Its purpose is to modify object after creation. I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate with JDBCTemplate.

```
listaProiecte is a List<Proiect>
```

Here is the form:

```
    <form:form method="post" id="modifica" action="/modifica" commandName="proiect">

    <div class="input-group col-md-12">

        <div class="input-group col-md-12">

            <div class="col-md-12"><br/></div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span>           </span>
                <sform:select path="idProiect" id="idProiectSelect"  cssClass="form-control input-sm">
                    <sform:option value="0" label="--- Select ---"/>
                    <c:forEach items="${listaProiecte}" var="proj">
                        <sform:option var="id" id="optiune"  value="${proj.idProiect}" label="${proj.nrProiect}  ${proj.numeProiect}"/>
                    </c:forEach>
                </sform:select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12"><br/></div>
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <span>Nume Proiect</span>
                <sform:input path="numeProiect" id="numeProiectInput" cssClass="form-control input-sm"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12"><br/></div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span>Numar Proiect</span>
                <sform:input path="nrProiect" id="nrProiectInput" cssClass="form-control input-sm"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12"><br/></div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span>An</span>
                <sform:input path="an" id="anInput" cssClass="form-control input-sm"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12"><br/></div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span>Client</span>
                <sform:select path="idClient" id="idClientInput" cssClass="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="0" label="--- Select ---"/>
                    <c:forEach items="${listaClienti}" var="clnt">
                        <sform:option value="${clnt.idClient}" label="${clnt.client}"/>
                    </c:forEach>
                </sform:select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12"><br/></div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn " id="btnMod">
                    Modifica Proiect
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

And the controller:

```
 @Qualifier("listaProiecteDAO")
    @Autowired
    private ListaProiecteJDBCDAO listaProiecteJDBCDAO;
    @Qualifier("clientiDAO")
    @Autowired
    private ClientiJDBCDAO clientiJDBCDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String proiecte(ModelMap map) {

        map.addAttribute("proiect", new ListaProiecte());
        map.addAttribute("listaProiecte", listaProiecteJDBCDAO.getAll());
        map.addAttribute("client", new Client());
        map.addAttribute("listaClienti", clientiJDBCDAO.getAll());

        return "admin";
    }
     @RequestMapping(value = "/modifica", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String moddProiect(@ModelAttribute(value = "proiect") ListaProiecte proiect, BindingResult result) {

        listaProiecteJDBCDAO.update(proiect);
        return "redirect:/admin#modProj";
    }
```

And the JS I am trying to use on the change() event of the select:

```
 $("#idProiectSelect").change(function(){
    var id = $("#idProiectSelect").val();
   $("#numeProiectInput").val(${listaProiecte[id].numeProiect});
   $("#nrProiectInput").val(${listaProiecte[id].nrProiect);
   $("#anInput").val(${listaProiecte[id].an);
   $("#idClientInput").val(${listaProiecte[id].idClient);

});
```

And apparently EL in ecmascript doesn't work. What is a workaround for this?
How do I use the id from the select box as a parameter for my List?

Answer (score 0):

Recommending to use freemarker and below mentioned is code to do the same.

This will be on the service side adding list of object to the model object.

```
@RequestMapping("/show")
    public String showFeesPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("batchlist", commonService.getBatchList());
        model.addAttribute("feeslist", commonService.getFeesList());
        return "fees";
    }
```

below mentioned u will be adding in the freemarker page.

```
<#list batchlist as batch>

    <option value="${batch.id}">${batch.batchName}</option>

</#list>
```

Comment: the form is to modify and object from the same list as the select box is selecting from